# Refused to frame 'lightning.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors visualforce.com"

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I update the code to below and I can preview the page. But when I add the page to Lightning app builder, it cannot load. And got the error `Refused to frame 'https://mirage-video-dev-ed--ltng.container.lightning.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://mirage-video-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com".`

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="hello" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:myFirstApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:container",
              { src: "{!$Resource.hello + '/index.html'}"},
              "hello",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("button was created");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );

        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

My myFirstApp.app

```
<aura:application access="global"  extends="ltng:outApp">
   <aura:dependency resource="lightning:container"/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of morphing your question by editing it.  That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things are missing in this code. Application needs to have **ltng:outApp** extended and VF Page should have the code block(some div with ID) to embed the body.

Reference to official documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm

Comment: thank you. It works now

Comment: but i encounter another problem. I updated the question